# Weird results using Solidify tool

Tags: modeling, sculpting, geometry, solidify-modifier

I am in the process of creating an asset for a character model, and when I try to use the Solidify tool to thicken the surface, I get a strange result where some faces thicken in the opposite direction, which messes up all the geometry. I've already looked at several tutorials and threads regarding similar topics, but nothing I am doing seems to be working. I've attached a couple screenshots and (will attach) the .blend file. I'm also fairly new to Blender, so I don't quite understand what I can do to fix these issues.

[image]

This is what the model looks like before the modifier.

[image]

This is what it looks like after.

My only theory as to why this is happening is that maybe the normals of those specific edges aren't aligned with everything else.

And here is the .blend:
[image]

Comment: You can investigate further in edit mode (be sure the "Display modifier in Edit mode" is turned on (button next to solidify Name), and in *Overlays*, you can enable Normals indicators for each face/edge, and enable Geometry >> Face Orientation.

Comment: Did you look at the object with Face Orientation checked on the View Overlays dropdown and have you selected All in Edit mode and used Shift-N to recalculate the normals?

Comment: 0.23m is 9 in, which seems like a lot !  If I add the "Monkey" to my view and use a 9" thckness, it certainly looks very odd.   What is the overall dimension of your mesh?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I didn't know that I could display normals in the veiwport, and after turning that on I was able to see that those face groups were turned opposite everything else. Using Shift+N worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try recalculating your normals

In *Edit Mode* go to the menu *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside* .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, disable the modifier in the viewport, turn on <kbd>Viewport Overlays</kbd> and check <kbd>Face Orientation</kbd> which shows this result:

[image]

Go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, select <kbd>A</kbd>ll then <kbd>⇧ Shift N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. That gives this result:

[image]